# Is there a way to have jq keep going after it hits an error?

Tags: jq

I am using jq to parse log data, occasionally the logs contain malformed stuff (invalid json), when this happens, jq aborts processing at that point.

Is there a way to have jq keep processing what it can, while reporting the problems via stderr?

I understand that if you have newlines in your JSON, jq may have trouble if it starts with the next line, but in such cases you will still eventually get to the point that you find the start of a legitimate json message and can continue processing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have jq 1.5, the answer is: *yes*, though in general, preprocessing (e.g. using hjson or any-json) would be preferable.

Anyway, the idea is simply to take advantage of the try/catch feature. Here is an illustration using the `inputs` filter.  Note that jq should in general be invoked with the -n option for this to work.

### recover.jq

```
def handle: inputs | [., "length is \(length)"] ;
def process: try handle catch ("Failed", process) ;
process
```

### bad.json

```
[1,2,3]
{id=546456, userId=345345}
[4,5,6]
```

### See jq run:

```
$ jq -n -f recover.jq bad.json
[
  "[1,2,3]",
  "length is 3"
]
"Failed"
[
  "[4,5,6]",
  "length is 3"
]
```

Comment: I was looking for something simpler, but you gave me the info needed. I'm not trying to do anything fancy, just extract a field. So I ended up doing  

     def handle: inputs | .originalmsg ;
    def process: try handle catch ("Failed", process) ;
    process

Answer (score 21):

With jq-1.5 I was able to do the following:

With this example file:

```sh
cat << EOF > example.log
{"a": 1}
{invalid
{"b": 2}
EOF
```

Output non-json lines as unquoted strings:

```sh
cat example.log | jq --raw-input --raw-output '. as $raw | try fromjson catch $raw'

{
  "a": 1
}
{invalid
{
  "b": 2
}
```

Silently skip non-json lines:

```sh
cat example.log | jq --raw-input 'fromjson?'

{
  "a": 1
}
{
  "b": 2
}
```

You can add `--slurp` if the entire input is expected to be a single multiline json blob.

Example files:

```sh
cat << EOF > valid-multiline.log
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
EOF

cat << EOF > invalid-multiline.log
{
  asdf
  "b": 2
}
EOF
```

Outputs

```sh
cat valid-multiline.log | jq --slurp --raw-input --raw-output '. as $raw | try fromjson catch $raw'

{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}

cat invalid-multiline.log | jq --slurp --raw-input --raw-output '. as $raw | try fromjson catch $raw'

{
  asdf
  "b": 2
}
```